# Do I write these using statements inside or outside the class?

Tags: c#, sql, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a class that I wrote that contains different methods that perform calculations on data pulled from my database. Each method pulls information from the database and performs calculations on it and then saves it to a variable in the class that I can access when I initialize the class. I have two pseudo code methods below and I'm trying to figure out the following:

1. Which way should I utilize the using statements if every method pulls data and then performs calculations on it?
2. Am I using the most efficient way to store the data?

This is what I do when I initialize the class

```
    public class Calculations
    {
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> stockPctReturns { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> marketPctReturns { get; set; }
    public enum returnType { Market, Stock };
    public decimal avgAnnualMarketGrowth { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> stockPctGains { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> stockPctLosses { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> positiveMoneyFlow { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> negativeMoneyFlow { get; set; }
    public decimal rsi { get; set; }
    public decimal mfi { get; set; }
    public decimal williamsR { get; set; }
    public decimal sma20 { get; set; }
    public decimal sma50 { get; set; }
    public decimal sma200 { get; set; }
    public const decimal riskFree10Yr = 2.58M;

    public Calculations(string symbol, string market)
    {
        // initialize everything in the class
        Symbol = symbol;
        Market = market;
    }
}
```

Do it this way:

```
public void fillPctReturns()
    {
        stockPctReturns = new List<decimal>();
        marketPctReturns = new List<decimal>();

        using (DailyGlobalDataTableAdapter dailyGlobalAdapter = new DailyGlobalDataTableAdapter())
        using (DailyAmexDataTableAdapter dailyAmexAdapter = new DailyAmexDataTableAdapter())
        using (DailyGlobalDataTable dailyGlobalTable = new DailyGlobalDataTable())
        using (DailyAmexDataDataTable dailyAmexTable = new DailyAmexDataDataTable())
        {
            dailyAmexAdapter.Fill(dailyAmexTable);
            dailyGlobalAdapter.Fill(dailyGlobalTable);
                    var amexQuery = from c in dailyGlobalTable.AsEnumerable()
                                    where c.Date >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(60))
                                    orderby c.Date descending
                                    join d in dailyAmexTable.AsEnumerable() on c.Date equals d.Date
                                    select new StockMarketCompare { stockClose = d.AdjustedClose, marketClose = c.AdjustedClose };

                    List<StockMarketCompare> amexResult = amexQuery.ToList();
// perform calculations here and save to stockPctReturns and marketPctReturns
         }
  }
```

Or should I do it this way:

```
using (DailyGlobalDataTableAdapter dailyGlobalAdapter = new DailyGlobalDataTableAdapter())
        using (DailyAmexDataTableAdapter dailyAmexAdapter = new DailyAmexDataTableAdapter())
        {
            Calculations calc = new Calculations();
            calc.Symbol = "GOOG";
            calc.Market = "nyse";
            dailyAmexAdapter.Fill(calc.dailyAmexTable);
            dailyGlobalAdapter.Fill(calc.dailyGlobalTable);
            calc.fillPctReturns();
        }
```

// this example would have public properties in the calculations class for the datatables and as you can see I set them like the above

Hopefully you can tell what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the second method you show does now allow you to wrap `dailyAmexTable` and `dailyGlobalTable` in using blocks, so if their respective classes implement `IDisposable` (which I assume they do based on your other code), then I would prefer the first method. This allows you to wrap all of your `IDisposable` instances in using blocks, which you should be doing.

The main thing with using blocks is that you generally want to close them as soon as you don't need them anymore in order to free up resources. As such, you should try to do your calculations **outside** the using block, unless you need to save something back to the database after performing calculations. So it would look something like this:

```
public void fillPctReturns()
{
    stockPctReturns = new List<decimal>();
    marketPctReturns = new List<decimal>();

    // Declare amexResult here so it is accessible outside the using block
    List<StockMarketCompare> amexResult;

    using (DailyGlobalDataTableAdapter dailyGlobalAdapter = new DailyGlobalDataTableAdapter())
    using (DailyAmexDataTableAdapter dailyAmexAdapter = new DailyAmexDataTableAdapter())
    using (DailyGlobalDataTable dailyGlobalTable = new DailyGlobalDataTable())
    using (DailyAmexDataDataTable dailyAmexTable = new DailyAmexDataDataTable())
    {
        dailyAmexAdapter.Fill(dailyAmexTable);
        dailyGlobalAdapter.Fill(dailyGlobalTable);
        var amexQuery = from c in dailyGlobalTable.AsEnumerable()
                        where c.Date >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(60))
                        orderby c.Date descending
                        join d in dailyAmexTable.AsEnumerable() on c.Date equals d.Date
                        select new StockMarketCompare { stockClose = d.AdjustedClose, marketClose = c.AdjustedClose };

        amexResult = amexQuery.ToList();

     }
     // perform calculations here and save to stockPctReturns and marketPctReturns
}
```

### EDIT:

Now that I see what you are doing more clearly, I would recommend having the using blocks outside of the class. the main reason is to make sure your code is **loosely coupled**, in this case meaning that the **data access** code is separate from the **business logic** (a.k.a calculations) code. One way to do this is to run your query outside of the calculations class, and pass the query result to a property in the calculations class. For example:

```
public class Calculations
{
    public List<StockMarketCompare> Data { get; set; }
    // (Other properties and methods omitted.)
}
```

Then in your calling function:

```
var calc = new Calculations();
using (DailyGlobalDataTableAdapter dailyGlobalAdapter = new DailyGlobalDataTableAdapter())
using (DailyAmexDataTableAdapter dailyAmexAdapter = new DailyAmexDataTableAdapter())
using (DailyGlobalDataTable dailyGlobalTable = new DailyGlobalDataTable())
using (DailyAmexDataDataTable dailyAmexTable = new DailyAmexDataDataTable())
{
    dailyAmexAdapter.Fill(dailyAmexTable);
    dailyGlobalAdapter.Fill(dailyGlobalTable);
    var amexQuery = from c in dailyGlobalTable.AsEnumerable()
                    where c.Date >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(60))
                    orderby c.Date descending
                    join d in dailyAmexTable.AsEnumerable() on c.Date equals d.Date
                    select new StockMarketCompare { stockClose = d.AdjustedClose, marketClose = c.AdjustedClose };

    calc.Data = amexQuery.ToList();
    calc.fillPctReturns();
    // Run any other calculations here.
    // Save data to DB here.
}
```

Comment: So I should do it this way in every method? I was just taught that you should never ever repeat the same code which is why I came up with the first method. Also if I save the results that it pulls from the database in the using statement, will I still be able to see that data if I access it outside the using statement?

Comment: You are correct - you should not repeat the same code if possible. Depending on what you are doing, you might want to create a private method that gets the data for you, and call that private method from all of your other methods.

Comment: And to answer your other question: yes, the data will be accessible outside the using block since you are calling `ToList()` inside the using block.

Comment: All I'm doing is pretty much the same as above except there are alot more methods that just perform different calculations. I call the class and call whatever method I need.

Comment: Ok. So all of the calculation methods work with the same data? Would you ever call 2 different calculation methods back-to-back?

Comment: I initialize the class and call each method one at a time to get the results for reach calculation and then I save the results to the database. For the most part they pull the same data

Comment: I see. If you want to save the calculations at the end, then you might want to do the calculations and saving in the using block to avoid opening extra database connections.

Comment: So just add the table adapter and table to the using block with the others? It would be a separate table from the database but I'm guessing that doesn't matter?

Comment: I've updated my answer with hopefully a better way to structure things. You will probably need to customize it to suit your needs, but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: That is very useful. Thank you! I just have one last question about your edit. Why is it important to separate the calculations from the data access stuff?

Comment: In general, you want to minimize the amount of coupling in your code. By loose coupling, I mean that changes to one area of the code (data access) should not affect other areas of the code (calculations) This makes your code more maintainable, more readable/understandable, and more testable. In your case, this also allows you to access the data from other places besides just your calculations class (in case your program gets bigger and you need more than just a single calculations class).